# How to specify "double *" type in libffi?

Tags: c, ffi, libffi

I need to dynamically invoke a function in C with the function name and the arguments (and their types) only known during runtime.

For that, I use `libffi` (Foreign Function Interface library). I need to specify that the argument is `double *` (pointer to `double` value). However, I do not understand how to do this, as there is only `ffi_type_double` and `ffi_type_pointer`.

How to make a composite type?

UPDATE: As answered by @user20716902 in the comment below, the FFI docs state "You should use this [`ffi_type_pointer`] for all pointers, regardless of their real type".

Comment: According to the docs you should use, `ffi_type_pointer`
A generic void * pointer. You should use this for all pointers, regardless of their real type.

Comment: OK, thank you! Yes, I should've read the docs first 